# 2 dispositivos conectado ao mesmo endereço via Wireless

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Estou utilizando Visual Studio 2017 para rodar aplicação. (ASP.NET MVC)

Como posso fazer outro computador conectar o mesmo endereço url: `192.XXXXXXXXXXX:56987`.

Ou seja: 2 computadores trabalhando no mesmo endereço, onde eu posso debugar o computador A e B.

Tenho 2 computadores conectados a mesma rede wifi.

**1 - Tentativa:**

Já fui na configuração do firewall do Windows > Adicionei nova regra ... (Nova porta configurada).

E ainda recebo o seguinte de erro:

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

**2 - Tentativa:**

Menu Iniciar > ISS > Associoções do site > Coloquei nova porta e IP.

O problema é o mesmo. "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname ..."

**3 - Tentativa:**

Já tentei colocar http://192.XXX.XXX.XXX:56987/

**4 - Tentativa:**

Já tentei a resposta do colega [Rovann Linhalis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206698/54019). O problema continua o mesmo.

**5 - Tentativa**:

Tentei a resposta do colega [Cigano Morrison Mendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206738/54019), o problema **mudou**.

Agora não é mais de "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname ...". Agora é:

> Service Unavailable HTTP Error 503.
>
> The service is unavailable.

*Alguma solução ?*

Comment: como usar o mesmo localhost? explique melhor seu objetivo para que possa te ajudar

Comment: Localhost é só o 'apelido' local de cada máquina. Use o IP da máquina na rede para acessar. Se não funcionar, pode ser o firewall do servidor (ou da rede) barrando.

Comment: Assim: O computador "A" tem visual studio instalado e ISS, computador "B" não tem nada,tem apenas um navegador. Como fazer o computador "B" com a mesma rede do "A".

Comment: @bfavaretto, voce tem algum link ou tutorial ? Sou novato essas coisas de rede.

Comment: Ligue os 2 no mesmo roteador e veja qual é o IP de cada um deles. Não tenho tutorial pra recomendar, mas deve ter vários no google.

Comment: A sua aplicação é executada em um navegador usando localhost e você quer acessar o work directory em outro computador é isso?

Comment: Isso @FelipeDuarte.

Comment: Voce está lembrando de por o protocolo? **`http://`** `IP:porta`, e não só `IP:porta`? dependendo do ambiente isto faz diferença.

Comment: @Bacco, sim já tentei tbm, o problema é o mesmo

Comment: Viu se seu roteador tem opção de 'isolar clientes wireless' ou coisa parecida? Tem roteador que nao permite comunicação entre pares sem fio. Teste com um cabo crossover de rede entre os 2 pcs, se puder, pra ver se não é isso (mas ai precisaria por IP manualmente). Ou teste por cabo, mesmo com o roteador.

Comment: Bem pensado, vou tentar aqui.

Comment: eu conversei com Matheus no chat, e é bem estranho... no mesmo computador que funciona a url localhost:porta, não funciona 127.0.0.1:porta nem mesmo com o nome da máquina

Comment: Pessoal obrigado a todos que gastaram o tempo pra me ajudar resolver o problema. O problema foi resolvido com a resposta do colega Cigano Morrison Mendez. Valeu pessoal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É preciso também permitir o uso do endereço especificamente para o caso do IIS Express, executando o seguinte em modo administrador:

```
> netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.25.50:56987 user=everyone
```

Note que isso não é uma configuração de *firewall*. É um permissionamento baseado em usuários.

---

Por ter tido um erro 503, mais algumas coisas precisam ser feitas:

1. Abra seu arquivo `applicationhost.config` file. Normalmente fica em `C:\Users\SeuUsuario\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` ou em
   `Diretório da Solução\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` (no caso do VS2015);
2. Localize a entrada do seu site no arquivo e adicione o seguinte:

   ```
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":56987:nomedasuamaquina" />
   ```
3. Reinicie o IIS Express.

Comment: Windows em português, certo? Use `user=Todos` no lugar.

Comment: Que estranho. Tem certeza de que está usando o IP da rede Wi-Fi certo pra fazer o comando?

Comment: Depois de longo tempo, `netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.25.50:56987/ user=Todos` era só adicionar `/` no final número. O problema mudou. Agora está: `Service Unavailable`

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Coloquei mais detalhes.

Comment: Cigano salvou meu dia, Obrigado :)

Comment: Só não entendo porque as pessoas querem fechar minha pergunta ...

Comment: [Me adicione no Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/cigano.m.mendez) que eu te explico o porquê.

Answer (score 5):

Considerando que os dois computadores já estão na mesma rede:

**1-Descubra o IP do seu computador A:**

abra um prompt de comando, o famoso cmd, e digite ipconfig. Verás essa tela:

[image: Ipconfig]

O seu endereço vai estar no "Endereço IPV4" no meu caso, 192.168.25.50

**2-Descubra a porta TCP utilizada pelo ISS, pode olhar direto na url aberta pelo visual studio quando você dá start no projeto:**

[image: url]

No meu caso, 2143, caso não tenha nenhuma porta informada (http://[host]:[porta]/[...]) será adotada a porta padrão HTTP, que é 80.

**3-Libere a porta (se necessário) no firewall do windows:**

Painel de Controle > Firewall do Windows > Configurações Avançadas > Regras de Entrada > Nova Regra > Porta > TCP | Portas locais específicas [informe sua porta] > Permitir Conexão > Todas as opções > DÊ um nome para sua regra > Concluir.

**4-No navegador do computador B, digite a mesma url que o visual studio abre pra você substituindo a parte do Host pelo IP do computador A.**

EX:

A: http://localhost:2143/Default.aspx

B: http://192.168.25.50:2143/Default.aspx

Comment: complementei a resposta,estava escrevendo ainda rsrs

Comment: não... é no firewall do computador A

Comment: desabilita o firewall do computador A para testes

Comment: O visual studio no computador A, está rodando o projeto né ?

Comment: quais os respectivos ips dos computadores A / B

Comment: Rovan Linhalis, qual é o caminho do hots ? Aquele suspeito ...

Comment: c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: Obrigado por você me ajudar. :)