# Como fazer para disponibilizar acesso HTTP para meu web service apache no Linux

Tags: linux, windows, servidor, docker

Para um simples programador estamos acostumados em criar servidores web e trabalhar em localhost, minha grande dúvida é, e na hora de deixar esse servidor online?

Hoje em dia temos **cloud** mas gostaria de saber quando eu tenho meu servidor local o modo que faço essa configuração para disponibilizar acesso.

Exemplo:

Tenho o IP da minha máquina 99.999.999.99

**Como expor o endereço da minha máquina para que qualquer pessoa que acessar caia na minha página web?**

Comment: basta colocar seu ip publico e liberar as portas no seu roteador / firewall... a porta padrao http é 80

Comment: use https://ngrok.com/ muito mais seguro e simula ssl

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206698/69359

Comment: Existe algum tutorial ensinando passo a passo? Além de me ajudar pode ajudar muito mais pessoas que estão passando por essa de configurar servidor kkkk

Comment: Detalhe, naveguei muito na net e nenhum tutorial dizia como disponibilizar na web o IP e direcionar para o servidor web. Por isso resolvi perguntar aqui

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, linkou uma resposta que responde exatamente sua pergunta, caso queira uma alternativa posso responder

Comment: Só me tira uma dúvida, a partir do momento em que eu crio uma regra de entrada disponibilizando uma porta meu IP neste momento já esta publico, certo? Depois é só eu iniciar o servidor da mesma forma que fazemos em desenvolvimento e colocar na mesma porta que eu criei regra de entrada. Dessa forma quando alguem solicitar meu IP nesta porta ela terá meu website. Esta certo isso?

Comment: Se tem de levar algumas coisas em conta: teu IP é fixo?

Comment: Sim, é fixo. Mas seria legal se vc pudesse mostrar exemplo caso fosse dinâmico

Comment: Assim se for dinâmico, vc só terá acesso, enquanto estiver sob tua concessão. Se mudar ai terá que acessar com o novo...

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma conta no NO-IP https://www.noip.com/pt-BR e a configure, tem bastante tutorial sobre isso na net.

Imagino que seu webserver esteja funcionando em sua rede local.
Agora basta vc redirecionar a porta 80 no seu roteador para o ip insterno de seu webserver.

Digamos que vc tenha criado o seguinte host no NO-IP
meuservidor.hopto.org

basta vc passar essa url para quem estiver fora da sua rede interna
Exemplo: 
http://meuservidor.hopto.org

Pronto, seu webserver estará acessível pela internet toda. ;)